# Im trying to create a slide ViewController like snapchats

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I copied this code for the sliding view controller from a YouTube snapchat like menu video but it won't compile.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        var V1 :  View1 = View1(nibName: "View1" , bundle: nil)

        self.addChildViewController(V1)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(V1.view)
        V1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)


    }
```

I keep getting the error use of undeclared type 'View1'. How do I fix this? I followed a tutorial and the code is identical. How do I declare View1 as a type?

Comment: Because complier don't know what `View1` is.Can you share a link of that tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

I've made the same tutorial but for three Views:

```
  @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let view1: View1 = View1(nibName: "View1", bundle: nil)

    addChildViewController(view1)
    scrollView.addSubview(view1.view)
    view1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    let view2: View2 = View2(nibName: "View2", bundle: nil)

    addChildViewController(view2)
    scrollView.addSubview(view2.view)
    view2.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    var view2Frame: CGRect = view2.view.frame
    view2Frame.origin.x = view.frame.width
    view2.view.frame = view2Frame


    let view3: View3 = View3(nibName: "View3", bundle: nil)

    addChildViewController(view3)
    scrollView.addSubview(view3.view)
    view3.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    var view3Frame: CGRect = view3.view.frame
    view3Frame.origin.x = view.frame.width * 2
    view3.view.frame = view3Frame

    self.scrollView.contentSize.width = view.frame.width * 3
  }
```

And this works just fine. Hope it helps.